# calculate conditional probability

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, probability

Input

```
cust_Id  category  product  purchased
1        Elec      light    0    
1        Elec      light    1
1        Elec      light    0
1        HA        Table    1
1        HH        Pen      1
2        Elec      light    0
2        HA        Table    1
3        HH        Pen      0
3        Elec      light    1
```

I want to know the best customer,category,product based on maximum probability value

Comment: what's `probability `?

Comment: P(purchased|Cust_id,cat,product)

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far (some codes)

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinskidf.groupby('cust_id').count()

Comment: Probability(purchased=0)= count(0)/len(df) (4/9=0.4444)                                                     prob(Purchased=1)= count(1)/len(df)(5/9=0.5555)

Comment: please edit the question rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grp = df.groupby(['cust_Id', 'category', 'product'])
prob = grp.sum() / grp.count()
```

Result is the probability that a particular combination of the 3 attributes will purchase something:

```
                          purchased
cust_Id category product           
1       Elec     light     0.333333
        HA       Table     1.000000
        HH       Pen       1.000000
2       Elec     light     0.000000
        HA       Table     1.000000
3       Elec     light     1.000000
        HH       Pen       0.000000
```

The probability of them **not** purchase anything is simply the complement of that (i.e. `1 - prob`)

Comment: For cust_Id 1 i have to select maximum purchased value,similarly for all cust_Id's

Comment: @jezrael For cust_Id 1 i have to select maximum purchased value,similarly for all cust_Id's

Answer (score 1):

If want divide `sum` with `count` it is definition of `mean`, so use:

```
out1 = df.groupby(['cust_Id', 'category', 'product'], as_index=False)['purchased'].mean()

out1 = (df.assign(zero = df['purchased'].eq(1))
          .groupby(['cust_Id', 'category', 'product'], as_index=False)['purchased'].mean())
```

If want count `0` values:

```
out0 = (df.assign(zero = df['purchased'].eq(0))
          .groupby(['cust_Id', 'category', 'product'], as_index=False)['purchased'].mean())
```